# Compiling opencv 2.4.5 with TBB

Tags: opencv, tbb

I have TBB installed to /usr/local/tbb and now trying to compile opencv 2.4.5 with the installed version.

But if i use ccmake, it will download another copy of TBB from the internet. I dont want this.

What are the commandline options for cmake to accept my local installed TBB directories?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

```
cmake -DWITH_TBB=ON
      -DTBB_INCLUDE_DIR=/usr/local/tbb/include
      -DTBB_LIB_DIR=/usr/local/tbb/lib
```